# Webpack build one module 1000+ times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am developing React app.

At the moment in my main app, I am using imports from an outside app (preparing the library for publishing - two directories up) which uses the same dependencies as the main app.

I have a problem that my web pack builds one component event 3000 times!

I added some aliases in web pack in the main app but it reduces only a little.

Has anybody clued how to get rid off thousands of builds the same component?

```
 53% building modules 4983/6870 modules 1887 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 4985/6870 modules 1885 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 4987/6870 modules 1883 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 4988/6870 modules 1882 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 4991/6870 modules 1879 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 4992/6870 modules 1878 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 4993/6870 modules 1877 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 4995/6870 modules 1875 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 5000/6870 modules 1870 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 5002/6870 modules 1868 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 5003/6870 modules 1867 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 5004/6870 modules 1866 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 5005/6870 modules 1865 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 5013/6870 modules 1857 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 5014/6870 modules 1856 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 5015/6870 modules 1855 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 5017/6870 modules 1853 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 5018/6870 modules 1852 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 5020/6870 modules 1850 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 5022/6870 modules 1848 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 5023/6870 modules 1847 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 5024/6870 modules 1846 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 5026/6870 modules 1844 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
 53% building modules 5036/6870 modules 1834 active ...\buttons\project\style.js
```

part of web pack config:

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
        "app-config": `./${NODE_ENV}.js`,
        recompose: path.resolve('./node_modules/material-ui/node_modules/recompose'),
        kotlin: path.resolve('./node_modules/kotlin'),
        warning: path.resolve('./node_modules/warning'),
        "hoist-non-react-statics": path.resolve('./node_modules/hoist-non-react-statics'),
        "object-assign": path.resolve('./node_modules/react-themeable/node_modules/object-assign'),
        "lodash.merge": path.resolve('./node_modules/webpack-merge/node_modules/lodash.merge'),
        isarray: path.resolve('./node_modules/isarray'),
        "material-ui": path.resolve('./node_modules/material-ui'),
        "@material-ui": path.resolve('./node_modules/@material-ui'),
        "lodash": path.resolve('./node_modules/lodash'),
        "lodash._baseEach": path.resolve('./node_modules/lodash._baseeach'),
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it could be recursive import of your component somewhere...